# constructor and copy constructor behaviour in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X
{
public:
    int g;
    X() { cout << "constr" << endl; }
    X(const X& ref1) { cout << "copy constr" << endl; }
};

X f()
{
    X ee;
    ee.g = 1;
    return ee;
}

int main()
{
    X ff = f();
    return 0;
}
```

Running the code I see that the constructor was called only once and the copy constructor was never called. Don't you expect two constructor and one copy constructor calls here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) called [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (the link explains precisely your case).

Answer (score 0):

**Copy Elision** is an optimization implemented by many compilers to prevent extra, unnecessary, copies. Makes the return-by-value or pass-by-value possible in practice.

Take a look at the example in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12953129/1938163

```
struct C {
  C() {}
  C(const C&) { std::cout << "A copy was made.\n"; }
};

C f() {
  return C();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  C obj = f();
}
```

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization#Summary)

Perhaps incredible to believe the first time, depending on the compiler & settings, the following outputs are all valid:

```
Hello World! 
A copy was made. 
A copy was made. 

Hello World! 
A copy was made.

Hello World!
```

In your case, this is a special copy elision optimization called [RVO - Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) where an object returned by value from a method has its copy elided.

Comment: when cut/pasting from Wikipedia you [normally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License) mention this explicitly

Comment: I posted the link entirely, but I'll mention it if you want.